# How Can I Solve Matrix Equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, equations

Say I have the following matrix equation

```
X - B*X*C = D
```

Where,
`X`: 3 by 5, to be solved;
`B`: 3 by 3;
`C`: 5 by 5;
`D`: 3 by 5;

Is there any convenient method that I can use for solving the system? fsolve?

Comment: Uh.. Linear algebra?

Comment: numerically? analytically?

Comment: @RoneyMichael Uh, I think so. Well, you can see I am not good at either Linear Algebra or Matlab.

Comment: Maybe asking in "Mathoverflow" will help you more! try ir if you dont get the answer here

Comment: @AnderBiguri Math Overflow is for research-level mathematics questions. You are probably thinking of [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor yeah my bad, you are rigth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case `B` or `C` are invertible, you can check the [matrix cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) section 5.1.10 deals with similar settings:

```
X * inv(C) - B * X = D * inv(C)
```

Can be translated to

```
x = inv( kron( eye, -B ) + kron( inv(C)', eye ) ) * d
```

where `x` and `d` are vector-stack of `X` and `D` respectively.

Comment: Wow, looks nice! I think I happened to download the book days ago but hadn't really had a look at it. Many thanks!

Comment: it's a great book. use it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATLAB's [dlyap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlyap.html) function:

```
X = dlyap(B,C,D)
```